# Adding a role to a specific user

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to add a role to a specific user. (using CronJob as an If)

```
function one() {
client.users.get("1234").addRole("4321");
}
```

returns

```
TypeError: client.users.get(...).addRole is not a function
                                 ^
```

tried the same with guild.members

Comment: The user has to be a GuildMember to do that. Try to find a user in a guild, then use addRole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your Answer @Jakye, I was able to do it as this:

```
let guild = client.guilds.get("111");
let user = guild.members.get("222");

function one() {
user.addRole("333");
}
```

I'm using Cron for function call.

Answer (score 1):

The user you want to give a role to must be a GuildMember. You need the guild ID and the user ID:

```
    let Guild = Client.guilds.get("613844301042024503");
    let User = Guild.members.get("223750026654908419");
    let Role = Guild.roles.get("615244847468642307");

    if (User) { // Checking if the user is a member of the guild.
        User.addRole(Role);
    } else {
        return message.channel.send("Couldn't do that. | The user is not a memer of the guild.");
    }
```